# Slow Initial Server Response

Tags: sql-server, iis, asp-classic

We have an ASP classic website running on an IIS 7.5 dedicated server with no other sites running on it.

The wait time for the homepage on the initial request is about 5.2 seconds but then subsequent wait times are a much more acceptable 133ms.

I am not sure why this is happening. Is there an app pool setting that I can check?

Comment: Have you checked `global.asa` to see what is being loaded on app start and on session start?

Comment: Initial request means first request per session or first request after pool recycle/application restart?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After a thorough investigation I discovered that the slow initial Time to First Byte was caused by the database connection string. A period "." was being used for the default server instance name rather than the name of the server being specified. When I changed the period to the server name the TTFB dropped to normal levels.

Thanks very much to all who answered.

Comment: Nice find.  I have dealt with this issue for years and just decided to find the solution.  This came up at the top of the search and solved it in five minutes.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

IIS7.5 has a [plugin which initializes applications](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-initialization) and helps reduce the slower performance of that initial load after an IIS restart or app pool recycle.

You can also install this via the Web Platform Installer.

Once installed you should notice there is a new option in the Advanced Settings of each IIS application pool allowed you to control this action on an application pool basis.

[image: application initialization settings]

Comment: Thanks Andy. I have installed the Application Initialization Module for IIS 7.5 but it has not helped the initial page load time. Could it perhaps be because my app pool is using Classic pipeline mode rather than Integrated pipeline mode?

Comment: All our Classic ASP sites run under Integrated pipeline mode fine on IIS7.5 so yes you could try that also.